# Can APK contains assets of androidTest folder/suite?

Tags: android, apk, apkanalyzer

I would like to know more about APK contents.
Will the release APK contains assets of test/androidTest folders?
I searched some for this.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apk_(file_format). But couldn't get the detail what I want.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. It contains only the main source set + Product flavor source set + build type source set.
androidTest/test - it's a testing source set. it's not including to the release apk.

Details about source sets:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build#sourcesets

You can also check your apk file with analyze apk:
Just to select ANdroid studio menu -> Build -> Analyze apk -> Select your apk.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer